# iOS Core Data: can't delete object with to-many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a Cruise object and an Events object. I'm trying to delete a single event.

Would post an image of my data model, but I don't have enough reputation yet...

The delete rules look like this:

(Cruise) cruiseEvents [Cascade] <------->> [Nullify] (Events) cruise

Here's the code:

```
NSLog(@"DELETE was selected for event:%@",_event);
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:_event];
    NSLog(@"IS DELETED?:%hhd",[_event isDeleted]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"DELETE ERROR????:%@",error.localizedDescription);
    _event = nil;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToEventList" sender:self];
```

Here is the debug log:

IS DELETED?:0

DELETE ERROR????:(null)

If I delete the cruise, everything cascades properly to delete the events. I just can't delete an individual event.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is it possible your MOC or event are nil?

Comment: Yes, just found that to be the case. Thanks.